# What's the best AIR & Ruby integration tool/framework?

Tags: ruby, air, adobe, integration

Well, I tried Shoes, Titanium, and RubyFX (or was it FXRuby?) and am not yet *quite* happy with the stability and cross-platform support from any of them as desktop application GUI tools. Next in line is Adobe AIR. Anyone know what the best tool is that will integrate Ruby and Adobe AIR? Is it even possible?

Comment: not related to your question, but did you check out wxRuby? It's a pretty mature cross-platform library...don't know how good the ruby bindings are though.

Comment: Just checked it out, and I'm not sure if it's for me...some of the conventions like "if you want to specify one non-default value, then you must specify all other optional values" seems scary and unconventional. But if that's the only option, then I guess I'll give it a go.

Comment: wxWindows (which wxRuby wraps) is a C++ library, so some of the conventions are going to be different than idiomatic ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that at the time of writing, there are no Ruby/AIR frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the better question might have been "is there an AIR/Ruby integration framework?" because I don't recall ever having seen such a thing...

Did you consider [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ruby+air+adobe) as a possible first port-of-call? ;-)

First result I got was some info at [RubyInside](http://www.rubyinside.com/adobe-integrated-runtime-air-resources-roundup-for-ruby-on-rails-developers-531.html).

However, the fact that this question is (as I write this) the #8 search result suggests that there may may not be much *to* find.

Beyond that, I'd also suggest taking  a look at [WxRuby](http://wxruby.rubyforge.org/wiki/wiki.pl), which seems - from a Windows-only perspective so far - to produce nicely native-looking UIs.

Comment: Looks like wxRuby & ocra are going to have to do the trick.

Comment: Sorry Mike, after thinking about this again, if an AIR/Ruby integration framework doesn't exist yet, then the answer remains unanswered. :-/ The RubyInside article doesn't seem to have solutions that would mesh the two and create a full standalone Ruby/Air app.

Comment: re "doesn't exist yet/unanswered": no disagreement here!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using jRuby and Swing? Using Ruby really makes Swing much more pleasant to work with.

Comment: Interesting idea, Mike. I'll have to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree that there isn't a framework that answers your question, per se.  But if you have a majority your rails stuff written, a good 'service wrapper' that you might want to look at is weborb.  We use it for our C# classes and it's only about 10Bil times faster than flat xml service calls (You'll still receive xml, but it will be serialized/deserialized --- may the FSM bless AMF.)

True, you'd still have to write a UI, which, by the wording of your question, I'm guessing you wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sort of thing you are looking for? http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop/

Comment: Yes, but I tried the latest release on Windows and on Linux. On Windows, the packager hung. On Linux, the 'sandbox' hung. And I need to feel comfortable that the product works on all three platforms. Maybe in 6 months or after they work out the kinks I'll re-evaluate the accepted answer.